# User authentication between a rails api and a node.js app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am attempting to understand how segmented apps work so I'm building one that uses rails for the back-end api and node.js for the front and middle. What I am trying to figure out is how to let a user log in through rails and use that same session information in the node app.

I have heard of oauth2, but I don't know if that's what I need or if I need something else. My main concern is that I want to keep all the models in the rails app so I can take advantage of the syntactic sugar and associations that rails provides. The node app will just connect to the rails app through it's api.

Are there any tutorials out there for this? Or does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer [here](http://zacstewart.com/2015/05/14/using-json-web-tokens-to-authenticate-javascript-front-ends-on-rails.html). Hope it can help someone else out